# How to change packaging structure in open api code generator input yml file

Tags: spring, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I am using open api generator tool to generate spring code using petstore.yaml from swagger  as input  file and I want to change the default packing structure while generating code. Can i change packaging structure if yes which  mustache file need modify

I want packaging like this
[image]

Comment: Please include your yaml file as inline text to your question.  The link you provided does not show the same yaml file for everyone (it uses cached resources to continue sessions).  Also, please include your maven settings so that there is a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Be sure to show what is happening vs what you want/expect to happen.  I see that you want a file structure, but what file structure are you getting now?  Where lies the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the openapi-generator cli you can specify output locations and package names (model and api) with command line arguments. The following will allow control of the package structure:

```
-o path/to/generated/code
--api-package foo.bar.api
--model-package foo.bar.model
--invoker-package foo.bar.client
--additional-properties <additional properties>
```

eg from npx

```
npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i api.json -g spring --additional-properties=library=spring-cloud -o ./ --api-package foo.bar.api --model-package foo.bar.model
```

eg from Java jar

```
java -jar modules/openapi-generator-cli/target/openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -i api.json -g spring --additional-properties=library=spring-cloud -o ./ --api-package foo.bar.api --model-package foo.bar.model
```

A full list is of parameters is [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/java.md). You need to turn the camelCase into kebab-case to use from command line.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using openapi-generator-maven-plugin to generate. You can specify output locations and package names (model and api) by using the plugin config in your project POM file as follows. A full list is of parameters [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${openapi-generator-maven-plugin-version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yaml/yamlfilename.yaml</inputSpec>
                <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                <apiPackage>${default.package}.handler</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>${default.package}.model</modelPackage>
                <invokerPackage>${default.package}.handler</invokerPackage>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>

</plugin>
```

Comment: no I am using open api generator tool for generating code